# mod_rewrite + htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a (Joomla) site that is not currently pointing to a domain, but is sitting directly on my server IP (i.e.: http://176.158.165.1/~sitename)

Whenever I try to test my mod_rewrite, I get 404 errors. I have tested on another site on the same server, but it works 100%. Could this problem be due to the direct link to the IP address?

My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
Redirect /google.html http://www.google.com
```

Thanks,

Dev

Comment: `Redirect` is not a mod_rewrite statement, it's in `mod_alias`  so you won't need the `RewriteEngine` bit. So you are getting a 404 when accessing `176.157.164.1/google.html`?

Comment: @Pekka - Correct. Odd that Redirect then works on another domain on the same server though.

Comment: Where is the htaccess located? You are taking the fact into account that this will not match your `sitename` folder?

Comment: @Pekka - Its in the root. I have tried adding `RewriteBase /~sitename`, but it still gives errors.

Comment: @Ye but you are looking to redirect `/google.html` in the root? Without the sitename?

Comment: @Pekka - Yes, is that a problem (related to the site not being on the correct domain as yet)?

Comment: Nope, if the `htaccess` is in the root (and not in `sitename`), it should work fine

Comment: @Pekka - Root being www / public_html correct? I'm losing my mind trying to find out whats happening here.

Comment: @Ye well, root being whatever `http://176.158.161.1/` points to

Comment: @Pekka - Ah ok I see. The htaccess is within the /~site/ folder. So then, once the domain is added, it would become the root (i.e.: http://www.site.com) and would then work?

Comment: @Ye probably. Try `Redirect  /~sitename/google.html http://www.google.com` to test whether this was it

Comment: @Pekka - It works. So basically once the site goes live, the original strings will work? Also, please add that last part as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: The original strings should work, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working in a subdirectory, you need to add the directory name regardless where the htaccess file is placed:

```
Redirect /~sitename/google.html http://www.google.com
```

you can also use `RewriteBase` but to be totally honest, I never really figured out how to get that working,  and I've been too lazy to sort it out.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Redirect 301 /google.html http://www.google.com
```

Try #2: (using mod_rewrite)

```
RewriteRule ^google\.html$ http://www.google.com [R=301,NC,L]
```